# Angular Routing - Are there any attributes you can add to routing config to hook onto in a component?

Tags: angular, angular-routing

Below is an example routing config that I have created. However in a couple of my components, I'd like to add and remove classes in my HTML based on a particular route. Is it possible to add any additional 'attributes' (where component and canActivate are) that I can somehow hook onto in my component?

For example "if URL.name = this"

```
{
    path: 'folders/:folderId/projects/:projectId/s',
    component: ProjectDetailComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuardService],
    children: [
        {
            path: 'edit',
            component: ProjectEditComponent,
            canActivate: [AuthGuardService],
            customName: EditPanel, // Something like this possible?
        },
    ],        
},
```

Apologies if this is a little vague.

Comment: Of course. Routes have a "data" attribute that can contain anything you want. Check out the docs at: https://angular.io/guide/router#configuration

Comment: Thanks All! Appreciate the time and answers!

Comment: You're welcome. Always glad to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure if it is the best way, but you can pass a `data` attribute with what you want like this:

```
{
    path: 'folders/:folderId/projects/:projectId/s',
    component: ProjectDetailComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuardService],
    children: [
        {
            path: 'edit',
            component: ProjectEditComponent,
            canActivate: [AuthGuardService],
            data: { type: 'editPanel' }
        },
    ],        
},
```

Then you can get this in your component:

```
export class ProjectEditComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        if (this.route.snapshot.data.type === 'editPanel') {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want are query params on your route. You can check for query params in the component by injecting ActivatedRoute into your component.

Your route would be `localhost:4200/folders/1234/projects/1234/s?name=this`

```
import { OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

export class SomeComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor (private route: ActivatedRoute) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
      if (params.name === 'this') {
        ...
      }
    });
  }
}
```